# How do I refactor this code so it doesn't throw this error "Property 'patient' does not exist on type 'Request<ParamsDictionary>"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, router

Here's is my code. I'm trying to use passport authenticate to store the info of patients specific to the token created for each person.

```
router.get("/current", passport.authenticate("jwt", { session: false }), (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    res.json({
        id: req.patient.id,
        fullName: req.patient.fullName,
        age: req.patient.age,
        email: req.patient.email,
        phoneNumber: req.patient.phoneNumber,
        address: req.patient.address,
        medicalHistory: req.patient.medicalHistory,

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a type intersection like this:

```js
req: Request & { patient: Record<string, any>}
```

Comment: The error goes away but a new error is thrown
```
No overload matches this call.
  The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '(req: Request & {    patient: Record<string, any>;}, res: Response) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '(req: Request & {    patient: Record<string, any>;}, res: Response) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, 
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your tsconfig.json?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by creating an interface that extends the Request type.

```
interface CustomRequest extends Request {
   patient?: any;
}
```